# Endpoint Configuration for FBX RTB

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-ads-api

I found the following on Facebook's docs, but there are no specifics as to where to set them.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/rtb/

> Endpoint Configuration
>
> FBX partners must provide URL endpoints to Facebook for both their
>   bid, notify, and error servers (these can be the same or distinct).

Can somebody let me know where I can configure these endpoints.

Thanks,
Chandana

Answer (score 1):

You integrate with Facebook as DSP (buy side). Facebook will send you bid requests, notify you about bids won and report errors if any. For this to happen you have to provide those three URLs to Facebook otherwise FBX will not be able to work with you. So this is not the question to Facebook, this is the question to you.